# Is There Any Explanation for Michael Eddington's "Lucky Loonie"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In the Star Trek Deep Space 9 episode "Blaze of Glory", Michael Eddington asks Benjamin Sisko about his "Lucky Loonie" that was left behind on the station when he was arrested.
The question comes as a bit of surprise since it's a complete 90 degree turn from their discussion about the Maquis and the fate of the Alpha Quadrant.

I want to know if there was a special in or out of universe reason to include this bit of dialogue in the episode; was it slipped in by the actor or somebody else working on the show who happened to have a real life Lucky Loonie, or does Michael Eddington happen to be a Canadian in the Star Trek universe? Canada is very rarely mentioned in Hollywood shows as it is, and the fact that Eddington just happens to have a 200 year old Canadian coin (and specifically mentions that it is Canadian) seems very odd.

Comment: This scene was entirely in the character of the episode.

Comment: Canada is repeatedly mentioned in SGA, just like America is repeatedly referenced in Doctor Who

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the memory alpha article on [Michael Eddington](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Michael_Eddington):

> Marshall and the viewers additionally learned Eddington was Canadian, a detail the writers included impulsively. As well as DS9's creative team having a few connections to Canada, the series had many fans in that country. *"And the fact that of all the semiregulars, it's poor Eddington who buys the farm just seemed like a very Canadian thing,"* Ira Behr remarked. Added Robert Wolfe, *"So we thought, what the heck."* Wolfe concluded, *"You just know he's going to die because he doesn't have his 'lucky loony' with him."*

Comment: Nice. I'm sure you quoted Memory Alpha exactly, but of course it's "Loonie" rather than "loony".